# Mongoose update only the values that have changed

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I have a PUT route to update value. I am hitting this route from two places. One is sending information about **details** and one about **completed**. The problem is that mongoose is updating booth even though it gets value from only one.

So if I send information about completed that it is true and latter I hit this route with new details (that dont have completed value) it will update completed also to false. How do I update just the value that was changed?

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Todo.findOne({_id:req.body.id}, (err, foundObject) => {
      foundObject.details = req.body.details
      foundObject.completed = req.body.completed
    foundObject.save((e, updatedTodo) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
      } else {
        res.send(updatedTodo)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Jackson hint I was managed to do it like this.

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Todo.findOne({_id:req.body.id}, (err, foundObject) => {
    if(req.body.details !== undefined) {
      foundObject.details = req.body.details
    }
    if(req.body.completed !== undefined) {
      foundObject.completed = req.body.completed
    }
    foundObject.save((e, updatedTodo) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
      } else {
        res.send(updatedTodo)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If you're updating a document, [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) it, don't save it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const updateQuery = {};

if (req.body.details) {
  updateQuery.details = req.body.details
}

if (req.body.completed) {
  updateQuery.completed = req.body.completed
}

//or
Todo.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id}, updateQuery, {new: true}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {

  } else {

  }
})

//or
Todo.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id}, {$set: updateQuery}, {new: true}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {

  } else {

  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson. I was managed to do it.  Checking just if(req.body.completed) didn't work when completed was false and I needed to change it to true. Instead I used if(req.body.completed !== undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Had a function similar to this my approach was this

```
const _ = require('lodash');

router.put('/update/:id',(req,res, next)=>{
       todo.findById({
        _id: req.params.id
    }).then(user => {
        const obj = {
            new: true
        }
        user = _.extend(user, obj);
        user.save((error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Status not Changed")
            } else {
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500);
    })
};
```

Taking **new : true** as the value you updating

Answer (score 0):

It gets kinda ugly as the fields to be updated get increased. Say 100 fields.
I would suggest using the following approach:

```
try {

    const schemaProperties = Object.keys(Todo.schema.paths)
    const requestKeys = Object.keys(req.body)
    const requestValues = Object.values(req.body)
    const updateQuery = {}

    // constructing dynamic query        
    for (let i = 0; i < requestKeys.length; i++) {
        // Only update valid fields according to Todo Schema
        if ( schemaProperties.includes(requestKeys[i]) ){
            updateQuery[requestKeys[i]] = requestValues[i]
        }
    }
    const updatedObject = await TOdo.updateOne(
        { _id:req.params.idd},
        { $set: updateQuery }
    );
    res.json(updatedObject)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: error });
}
```